# Deleting a webhook message posted to Teams channel

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I developed code to post a webhook message to teams channel. Sometimes, there are cases where the posted message should be deleted. But I do not see or have an option in the teams message to delete, or my administrator is not allowed to add a delete option.

Is there a way where I can delete the teams message posted via webhook through C# code? I am able to get the `messageId` connected with the webhook message.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to delete the Teams message posted via webhook through csharp code.

Comment: Is there any other way to delete a webhook message posted to teams with out additional admin permissions?

Comment: @Kurkula as alternative, since you are able to get the message_id, can you edit it? - if so, consider clear the comment - "with an empty string" or by replacing the text with: *this message was deleted* or some on those lines.

Comment: I do not see option to clear message from teams message options.

Comment: @Kurkula Am I correct in assuming that you can get the message ID only through the API but not through the Teams app? That's the behavior I'm seeing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can now delete (and un-delete) Microsoft Teams messages via Graph APIs**

> There are two new API endpoints that developers can now use when working with Microsoft Teams chat messages.
>
> These mirror behavior that has been available in the Teams client for a while: the ability to delete a message, and then un-delete it if required).

Microsoft have chosen not to use the DELETE method, but instead use a POST method to a `/softDelete` method with an empty body:

```
POST /teams/{teamsId}/channels/{channelId}/messages/{chatMessageId}/softDelete
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-softdelete?view=graph-rest-beta&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5001530&tabs=csharp#example-2-soft-delete-message-in-a-channel) is the C# code for calling this API to delete message softly, from a teams channel:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

await graphClient.Teams["{team-id}"].Channels["{channel-id}"].Messages["{chatMessage-id}"]
         .SoftDelete.PostAsync();
```

Some useful sources links are:

- https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2022/07/you-can-now-delete-and-un-delete-microsoft-teams-messages-via-graph-apis/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-softdelete?view=graph-rest-beta&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5001530&tabs=csharp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-undosoftdelete?view=graph-rest-beta&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5001530&tabs=http

Comment: What permissions are required for graph under app registration? Does it require admin consent? Admin consent is not allowed as per my company's policies.

Comment: @Kurkula I was wondering the same thing. Creating via webhook but deleting via Graph API feels like a really odd workflow given they require totally different authentication schemes.